# is there a standard character encoding for war files?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, war

If I create a text file on an operating system that uses the Latin encoding code page ISO/IEC 8859-1.  Now if I package the text file as a .war file using the Java jar tool, will it be packaged using the same character encoding as it was on the source Operating System? Or, will it be packaged using some standard encoding such as UTF-8?

Comment: Packing (Creating the zip archive) will not change the encoding of any files.

Comment: How does the receiver of a .war/.jar file know the contents of a text file included?  Is the source encoding stored somewhere?  If not there does not seem to be any way to know is the content of an included text file if the original encoding is not changed to a standard encoding.

Comment: The receiver can't in general know. But any text files included should really only be read by the Java software in the jar file, so this is not really a problem. The only exception is the xml files which document the content of the .jar files. Those contains a xml header which document their encoding.

Comment: "so this is not really a problem" -- does it mean that the source operating system encoding will be used?

Comment: No. But the text files should only be read by either: The java software included in the jar, or the servlet container which is configured by a configuration file in the jar file. And this is the entire point: The software which read the text file is made by/configured by the same user who made the entire jar file. So I can encode all textfiles in my jar files as utf-7 if I want to. Then I just have to configure the software/webserver to read utf-7 files.

Comment: that sounds like the text files go into the jar exactly the same bytes stored in the source OS. so source OS could have default UTF-16, but text files could be stored as UTF-7, and java software configured to read/write UTF-7. jar tool would have no idea about UTF-7 but it would not matter because it would not alter the bytes as it reads from the text file and the java software would be able to decode using UTF-7.  **i. e., jar treats text files as binary**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like jar takes the bytes from the text file and stores exactly those bytes in the jar/war file without storing any encoding information.  This is gleaned from comments on the question as well as the other answers. The answers do not state this clearly, so I am answering my own question. Please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The character set encoding for JAR/WAR/EAR is UTF-8. Note however, that this only applies to the **entry names**, not the file contents, e.g. class file data.

Answer (score 0):

WAR file is basically a ZIP archive with .war extension and it has nothing to do with encodings.

Comment: i'm confused. the larger question is how does somebody know what are the contents of a text file that is included in a .war/.jar/.zip file?  Without knowing the encoding you can't tell what the contents are. Is the source encoding stored in the .war file?

Comment: It's not about the content, it's about the how file is used. The WAR extension is a sign for a Web Server that this is a WebARchive, nor JavaARchive or EnterprizeARchive.

Comment: File encoding are not supposed to be stored for text files by ZIP archiver, as far as I know.

Comment: i know that war extension is for web server.  how does the web server know what is the content of an included text file?

Comment: Web server doesn't need to know what is the content of a file. It's up to an application how to work with files.

Comment: HTTP requests can have Accept-Charset header which tells the web server what charsets the requestor can handle. This seems to imply the web server needs to understand character sets.

Comment: You're mixing up HTTP requests and files stored on the server. That encoding headers are mostly for browsers in order to show text properly.

Comment: hmmmm... i'm sorry i don't see how all of that fits together logically

Comment: If there is a text file within a JAR/WAR/EAR file, then it's the applications responsibility to use the correct character set for decoding - see InputStreamReader constructors - it's not part of the JAR specification.